# IIS to SQL Server Error 26, Same connection string works outside of IIS but not from within

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, .net-4.0, sql-server-2012

I have gone through every checklist I could find for configuring SQL Server I could find.  I get the same issue on Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7 Pro.  First the environment:

- SQL Server Express 2012 --installed as main instance (i.e. no named instances)
- IP access turned on
- Firewall exception for SQLServer
- SQL Server user for application access
- Windows Server 2008 service pack 2 (also tested with Windows 7 service pack 1)
- IIS 7 (also tested with 7.5 with the same results)
- .NET 4.0
- Our own database code integrated in a .NET MVC 3 application

We have a tool we developed to import data from the old Ruby on Rails app into the new ASP.NET MVC 3 app.  The tool can connect to the database using the user account we created, and that's how I discovered some permissions issues for access to stored procedures.  This is the tool we are using to verify the connection works.

> Data Source=SERVER_IP,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Database=MYDB;User ID=webuser;Password=webpassword;multipleactiveresultsets=true;

We are using a straight IP address, but to protect our infrastructure I substituted the IP, username, and password.  But this is the structure of the connection string we are using.  Following the checklists, I was able to connect from another machine on our network using the import tool to the database and import data.  I was also able to import data from the same machine that IIS is installed on.

The same connection string provides the dreaded Error 26 "can't find the database server" message on both Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7 Pro:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I have exhausted every resource I can find, and can't seem to get any closer to an answer.  I'm not trying to mount file based database, IIS has read/write access to the web application in any case.

---

I've ruled out the firewall as a cause for the issue.  I've tried the settings with the firewall on and completely turned off.  There has to be some other permissions level problem that's happening.  Problem is I have no idea what permissions level things I have to check.

Comment: Telnet from a command line to the server and port 1433 - can you get there?

Comment: Connect from the same machine and a different machine and I get there.  I have a utility that uses the connection and everything is fine until I try to access the database from IIS.

Comment: Like I said, I went through every checklist I could find.

Comment: wireshark it, see if any traffic is going out.

Comment: I think the problem is related to the fact that the operating system was not activated yet.  Same set up on the developer box (activated OS) allows connections from IIS to DB server.  It appears Windows crippled Windows to prevent using unactivated instances to host web sites.  Very frustrating in that it puts procurement in the way of getting testing done in a very small 50c3 group team.

Comment: hmm thats interesting. So your app 'works' but does not allow network access, or..?

Comment: My app works on a properly installed OS that is activated.  I'm getting a new VM with a properly activated OS to get testing done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening a ticket with Microsoft, it turns out I was my own worst enemy.  The model classes were set up in their own DLL so I could use them for data migration and other supporting tools for the website.

The DLL was looking in the assembly config for the connection string, and if it wasn't found it would use a reasonable default.  Problem is the web application never overrode the location from the Web.config file.

The application couldn't find it because I didn't install the database with the default settings.